# Can we modify the execute around idiom to use a mutable self?

Tags: rust, transactions, rust-diesel

## Short summary

I'm unable to find a way to wrap `diesel`s transaction API in my own API, due to diesels use of the "execute around" idiom for transaction handling coupled with its non-`&mut self` arguments.
This means I currently have to make some functions which really should mutate state also non-`&mut self` and use interior mutability. This feels ugly and I'm wondering if there is a workaround.

## Long version

The rust diesel library uses a technique like the "execute around" idiom for handling transactions. For example, to use it to insert two names into a database within a transaction would look like this.

```
pub fn perform_insert_two_names_transactionally<C:Connection>(
    conn: &C,
    name1: &str,
    name2: &str) {

    conn.transaction::<_, Error, _>(|| {

        diesel::insert_into(users)
            .values(name.eq(name1))
            .execute(&conn)?;

        diesel::insert_into(users)
            .values(name.eq(name2))
            .execute(&conn)?;

        Ok(())
    })?;
}
```

The signature for the `transaction` function is

```
fn transaction<T, E, F>(&self, f: F) -> Result<T, E>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, E>,
    E: From<Error>,
```

We can create a simplified version of this so that we don't need to build with diesel and define tables etc. We're really only using it for type and borrow checking.

```
pub struct Connection {}

pub enum ConnectionError {}

impl Connection {
    pub fn add_user(&self, name: &str) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn transaction<T, E, F>(&self, f: F) -> Result<T, E>
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, E>,
    {
        self.begin_transaction();
        let result = f();
        if result.is_ok() {
            self.end_transaction();
        } else {
            self.abort_transaction();
        }
        return result;
    }
    fn begin_transaction(&self) {}
    fn end_transaction(&self) {}
    fn abort_transaction(&self) {}
}

pub fn perform_insert_two_names_transactionally(
    conn: &Connection,
    name1: &str,
    name2: &str,
) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
    conn.transaction(|| {
        conn.add_user(name1)?;
        conn.add_user(name2)?;
        Ok(())
    })?;

    Ok(())
}
```

The key thing to note is that the `add_user`, and `transaction` functions **do not** take `&mut self`, just `&self` and this feels like a lie. In my version, I'd like them to take `&mut self` so that it is more clear that they are changing the application state.

If we try changing the usage of `&self` to `&mut self` (see this [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=41168a84dacda483a096e9b76fc46bc3)) we get the following error:

```
error[E0501]: cannot borrow `*conn` as mutable because previous closure requires unique access
  --> src/lib.rs:32:5
   |
32 |       conn.transaction(|| {
   |       ^    ----------- -- closure construction occurs here
   |       |    |
   |  _____|    first borrow later used by call
   | |
33 | |         conn.add_user(name1)?;
   | |         ---- first borrow occurs due to use of `conn` in closure
34 | |         conn.add_user(name2)?;
35 | |         Ok(())
36 | |     })?;
   | |______^ second borrow occurs here
```

We can get around this constraint by changing the signature of the function passed to `transaction` to accept a `&mut Connection`, which can then be used to perform the mutable calls.

```
pub struct Connection {}

pub enum ConnectionError {}

impl Connection {
    pub fn add_user(&mut self, name: &str) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn transaction<T, E, F>(&mut self, f: F) -> Result<T, E>
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut Connection) -> Result<T, E>,
    {
        self.begin_transaction();
        let result = f(self);
        if result.is_ok() {
            self.end_transaction();
        } else {
            self.abort_transaction();
        }
        return result;
    }
    fn begin_transaction(&mut self) {}
    fn end_transaction(&mut self) {}
    fn abort_transaction(&mut self) {}
}

pub fn perform_insert_two_names_transactionally(
    conn: &mut Connection,
    name1: &str,
    name2: &str,
) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
    conn.transaction(|conn| {
        conn.add_user(name1)?;
        conn.add_user(name2)?;
        Ok(())
    })?;

    Ok(())
}
```

The core problem is that when wrapping the diesel transactions we don't have access to `begin_transaction`, `end_transaction` and `abort_transaction` -- we need to use the `diesel::Connection::transaction` function instead.

The simplified version of this is

```
pub struct DieselConnection {}
pub struct WrapperConnection {
    pub conn:DieselConnection
}

pub enum ConnectionError {}

impl DieselConnection {
    pub fn add_user(&self, name: &str) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn transaction<T, E, F>(&self, f: F) -> Result<T, E>
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, E>,
    {
        self.begin_transaction();
        let result = f();
        if result.is_ok() {
            self.end_transaction();
        } else {
            self.abort_transaction();
        }
        return result;
    }
    fn begin_transaction(&self) {}
    fn end_transaction(&self) {}
    fn abort_transaction(&self) {}
}

impl WrapperConnection {
    pub fn add_user(&mut self, name: &str) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
        self.conn.add_user(name)
    }
    pub fn transaction<T, E, F>(&mut self, f: F) -> Result<T, E>
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut WrapperConnection) -> Result<T, E>,
    {
        self.conn.transaction( || { f(self) } )
    }
}

pub fn perform_insert_two_names_transactionally(
    conn: &mut WrapperConnection,
    name1: &str,
    name2: &str,
) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
    conn.transaction(|conn| {
        conn.add_user(name1)?;
        conn.add_user(name2)?;
        Ok(())
    })
}
```

also available on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6fe986d82951b8001d4768c53b85808c).

However, this gives the following error:

```
error[E0500]: closure requires unique access to `self` but it is already borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:38:32
   |
38 |         self.conn.transaction( || { f(self) } )
   |         --------- -----------  ^^     ---- second borrow occurs due to use of `self` in closure
   |         |         |            |
   |         |         |            closure construction occurs here
   |         |         first borrow later used by call
   |         borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
```

again, this makes sense.

I don't think this can be worked around by placing the connection in a `RefCell` or similar - but I'd love to be told I'm wrong.

At the moment I've just given up on wrapping the API in a way that matches my mutability expectations - my functions are all pretty much all using `&self` and work around the need for mutability using interior mutation using `RefCell` on their own data.

Is there some way wrap an API like the diesel transaction API and get the mutability types that I want?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work around this by noting that if we could clone the wrapped connection we could write the transaction wrapper as

```
impl WrapperConnection {
    pub fn transaction<T, E, F>(&mut self, f: F) -> Result<T, E>
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut WrapperConnection) -> Result<T, E>,
    {
        let conn_copy = self.conn.clone();
        conn_copy.transaction( || { f(self) } )
    }
}
```

(which compiles if you add `#[derive(Clone)]` to `DieselConnection`)

But in reality, the base connection doesn't implement `Clone`. So instead of storing a `DieselConnection` in the `WrapperConnection` we can store a `Rc<DieselConnection>`, which does implement `Clone`.

The full working code is:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct DieselConnection {}

pub struct WrapperConnection {
    pub conn: Rc<DieselConnection>,
}

pub enum ConnectionError {}

impl DieselConnection {
    pub fn add_user(&self, name: &str) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn transaction<T, E, F>(&self, f: F) -> Result<T, E>
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, E>,
    {
        self.begin_transaction();
        let result = f();
        if result.is_ok() {
            self.end_transaction();
        } else {
            self.abort_transaction();
        }
        return result;
    }
    fn begin_transaction(&self) {}
    fn end_transaction(&self) {}
    fn abort_transaction(&self) {}
}

impl WrapperConnection {
    pub fn add_user(&mut self, name: &str) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
        self.conn.add_user(name)
    }
    pub fn transaction<T, E, F>(&mut self, f: F) -> Result<T, E>
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut WrapperConnection) -> Result<T, E>,
    {
        let temp_conn = self.conn.clone();
        temp_conn.transaction(|| f(self))
    }
}

pub fn perform_insert_two_names_transactionally(
    conn: &mut WrapperConnection,
    name1: &str,
    name2: &str,
) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
    conn.transaction(|conn| {
        conn.add_user(name1)?;
        conn.add_user(name2)?;
        Ok(())
    })
}
```

which can be found in the rust playground [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=13c39c5708c3cf94d6253500c8920643).